# Installed Hardie board with tin roof

Tags: kitchens, outdoor, roofing, cement-board

Installed Hardie board, silver side down as ceiling with tin applied as roof. Can this type of application withstand being the roof/ceiling in an outdoor kitchen with no side walls?

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't clear to me. Please revise to use more words and add photos, if possible.

Comment: What kind of support is holding it up? What is the spacing of the supports? What, exactly, are your concerns - strength, weather resistance, appearance?

Comment: The Hardie board I'm famailiar with is a tile backer with both sides gray, no silver side, so I assume you are speaking of some other product (for that part.) What climate is this outdoor kitchen in (is freezing an issue, for instance? If so, you might have issues with the board delaminating if it's damp and then is frozen - I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Hardi makes a lot of out siding, she could be talking about that.   We probably need pictures.